# Receive and send observable in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have existing and working code, which looks like this (unnecessary stuff removed):

```
queryTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
            .throttle(.milliseconds(300), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .flatMapLatest { query in
                return try AddFriendViewController.getSearchResults(query)
                    .retry(3)
                    .startWith([])
                    .catchErrorJustReturn([])
            }
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: AddFriendTableViewCell.self)) { (row, item, cell) in                
                cell.nameLabel.text = "\(item.firstName) \(item.lastName)"
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

When you type a name in a text field it automatically searches (through an API) for friends matching this query.

But I also want to add another feature - import from contacts, invoked by additional button. I have a list of local contacts and using them I ask API for search results. I want to display these results in the same place. But I don't know how to *send* these results into tableView. I thought of creating a varabiable:

```
var items: Observable<[FriendSearchResult]> = Observable.just([])
```

But I don't know how to send/receive data. Any clues?

**edit:**

Thanks to @andromedainative now code looks like this:

```
var items: BehaviorRelay<[FriendSearchResult]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [])

items.asObservable()
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: AddFriendTableViewCell.self)) { (row, item, cell) in                
            cell.nameLabel.text = "\(item.firstName) \(item.lastName)"
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

queryTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
        .throttle(.milliseconds(300), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMapLatest { query in
            return try AddFriendViewController.getSearchResults(query)
                .retry(3)
                .startWith([])
                .catchErrorJustReturn([])
        }
        .bind(to: items) //this was a missing piece
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

And passing results from getContacts is simple:

```
items.accept(data)
```

But, I have a special case where I have to refresh data. How can I invoke queryTextField to call API with the same query?

I've only found a hacky way:

```
let query = queryTextField.text ?? ""
queryTextField.text = ""
queryTextField.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
queryTextField.text = query
queryTextField.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
```

I have to change to some other value and change it back. Is there any more clean solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitly use rx to bind your objects to your table view. I use BehaviorRelay for my arrays because I like to be able to access the .value property of the items.

This is a very psuedo code anser so it won't compile but I hope you get the gist of it:

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewController {

  private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

  var myItems: BehaviorRelay<[FeedItem]>

  func bindData() {

    tableView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)

    myItems.asObservable()
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { [weak self] tableView, row, myItemType in
            guard let `self` = self else { return UITableViewCell() }
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
            let myItem = self.myItems.value[indexPath.row]
            let myCell = tableView.dequeueCell(reuseIdentifier: "MyIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCellType

            return myCell
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I get that, but the issue is how to connect these 2 cases.

Comment: That is simple, just add the values from the items in the other button call to the same array.

So first you have the queried results that you add to the array.
var queriedResults = [SomeItems]

Then you have the items you get from your button press.
func handleButtonPress() {
    ...
    let myNewImportedContacts = [SomeItems]
    myItems.accept(myItems.value + myNewImportedContacts)
    // And now you have both in the same table view data source
}

Comment: Let me ask this in different way. What should I call after flatMapLatest to pass the results to items?

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you want to combine the values emitted by two or more observables, you need to use one of `combineLatest`, `zip`, `withLatestFrom`, or `merge` (possibly with `scan`). It depends on the context which one you should use. This article might help: [Recipes for Combining Observables in RxSwift](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/recipes-for-combining-observables-in-rxswift-ec4f8157265f)

Here's an idea for your specific situation. The code below adds a couple of functions that you will need to implement: `func getContacts() -> Observable<[Contact]>` and `func getSearchResults(_ contact: Contact) -> Observable<[Friend]>`.

```
let singleSearchResult = queryTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
    .debounce(.milliseconds(300), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .flatMapLatest { query in
        return try getSearchResults(query)
            .retry(3)
            .startWith([])
            .catchErrorJustReturn([])
    }

let contactsSearchResult = checkContactsButton.rx.tap
    .flatMapLatest { getContacts() }
    .flatMapLatest {
        Observable.combineLatest($0.map {
            getSearchResults($0)
                .catchErrorJustReturn([])
        })
        .startWith([])
    }
    .map { $0.flatMap { $0 } }

Observable.merge(singleSearchResult, contactsSearchResult)
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: AddFriendTableViewCell.self)) { (row, item, cell) in
        cell.nameLabel.text = "\(item.firstName) \(item.lastName)"
}
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

BTW, your `getContacts` should not be throwing. Its errors should emit from the Observable, not throw. Also, you should use debounce on your text field, not throttle. The latter is better suited to Void types, not Strings.

Comment: Nice hints, thanks. However, in my case I don't want to merge data, but rather replace it. I just used accept, as I stated in my edited answer (you may like to help mi just another issue that came out from this setup, see my edit).